# Building Python Extension Packages for Launchpad

Tags: python, ppa, launchpad, automake

I have an autotools project (c++) which I build packages for on a [launchpad ppa](https://launchpad.net/~valhalla-routing/+archive/ubuntu/valhalla)

Recently I've attempted to add a python package to that archive. I've tested it locally with `bzr dh-make` and also using `pbuilder`. Both work fantastically. On launchpad though no joy.

One of the builds logs is [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/301370384/buildlog_ubuntu-xenial-amd64.libvalhalla2.0.4_2.0.4-0ubuntu1~xenial1_BUILDING.txt.gz)

You'll see the problem is with the autogenerated install target. When it goes to install the python module it gives a warning and then re-links the module. I did a quick bit of research and [it seemed completely ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659569/what-is-relinking-warning)

[Here is](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~valhalla-routing/+junk/valhalla_2.0.4-0ubuntu1/view/head:/libvalhalla/Makefile.am#L375) the `Makefile.am` with the added python module target: 
The error in the build log on launchpad ends up saying:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvalhalla
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
libtool:   error: error: relink 'valhalla.la' with the above command before installing it
Makefile:2265: recipe for target 'install-pyexecLTLIBRARIES' failed
make[3]: *** [install-pyexecLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
```

Whats odd is that not all of them failed. Maybe it is something to do with concurrency.

I noticed that the command it runs is `make -j4 install` and then when relinking it seems to say can not find `-lvalhalla` which is the name of the main library the project creates. It seems to be installing multiple things simultaneously perhaps this is the issue. Maybe I can override just the `dh_auto_install` target in the `debian/rules` file?

Looks like someone else can confirm the same as what I'm seeing in this [list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-libtool/2011-11/msg00013.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So indeed it did turn out that the problem was to do with parallel builds and in particular at the end when the python module is being re-linked other stuff hasn't been isntalled yet. The fix was also indeed less of a fix and more of a work around and is exactly what i proposed.

Namely I simply added this target to my `debian/rules` file:

```
#because python module depends on main library and somehow dependency is not known we must limit parallelism
override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install --max-parallel=1
```

The `--max-parallel=1` bit will limit it to running `make -j1 install` which will avoid the race condition where libtool is looking for a lib that isn't there yet (described in the link above) when relinking the python module.